# Replace path in text file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line, scripting, text-files

I want to remove the path `G:\Data\editor\` from a text file and replace it with `..\` using powershell.

How do I go about doing that?

```
powershell -Command "(gc sample.txt) -replace 'G:\Data\editor\', '..\' | Out-File -encoding ASCII sample.txt"
```

[image]

---

I had used the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir), but it doesn't seem to be working when looking for a path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\` is used as the *escape character* in regular expressions, so in order to represent the *verbatim* (literal) `\` characters in your path, you must use `\\`:

```
powershell -Command "(gc sample.txt) -replace 'G:\\Data\\editor\\', '..\' | Out-File -encoding ASCII sample.txt"
```